# Simplification of hypergeometric function with specific arguments

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function

I have the following expression

$$A(x) = d \, {}_2 F_1(1/2 - i/2, 1; 3/2-i/2; 1-e^x) + \bar{d} \, {}_2 F_1(1/2 - i/2, 1; 3/2-i/2; 1-e^x), $$ where $d$ is a complex number and $\bar{d}$ its complex conjugate, $x$ is real and ${}_2 F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is the hypergeometric function.

This comes from an integral involving the product of logarithms, exponentials and cosines. Though numerically is checked that $A$ has no imaginary part, I wonder if I can further simplify things of the form

$$ A(x) = d \, _2F_1(a,b;c;x) + \bar{d} \, _2F_1(\bar{a},b;\bar{c};x) $$

I have looked up in Abramowitz & Stegun, but I fail to find such a simplifying property. Does anyone have a thought? I would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The hypergeometric function with these specific parameters can be reduced to Incomplete Beta function. But this doesn't solve the problem. I don't think that there is a simpler closed form. It is probably necessary to use numerical calculus (with the integral form or with series expension).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JJacquelin. Please, could you elaborate some more on expressing the hypergeometric in terms of the Beta function? Would the arguments for the Beta function still remain complex? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $${}_2 F_1(a,b;a+1;x)=ax^{-a}B_x(a,1-b)$$
$a=\frac{1-i}{2}$ ; $b=1$ 
$${}_2 F_1(\frac{1-i}{2},1;\frac{3-i}{2};x)=\frac{1-i}{2}x^{-\frac{1-i}{2}}B_x(\frac{1-i}{2},0)$$